# How can I return true if a specific object was found in an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a simple form with checkboxes made in Angular and I would like to make the checkbox check itself if the user has this role.

Here is what I tried:

```html
<form [formGroup]="rolesForm">
  <label 
    formArrayName="roles" 
    *ngFor="let role of rolesForm.controls['roles'].controls; let i = index"
  >
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      [checked]="checkIfTrue(role[i])"
      [formControlName]="i" 
    /> {{role[i].name}}
  </label>
</form>
```

The component itself:

```js
roles: Role[] = [
  {
    uid: '456DNC',
    name: 'Admin'
  },
  {
    uid: '546DKZ',
    name: 'Member'
  },
  {
    uid: '741JXY',
    name: 'Guest'
  }
]

user: User = {
  uid: '123ABC',
  name: 'Steve',
  roles: [
    {
      uid: '456DNC',
      name: 'Admin'
    }
  ]
}

rolesForm: FormGroup;

// So I can get every roles and the user can check multiple checkboxes to get as many roles as it wants
ngOnChanges() {
  const formControls = this.roles.map(role => new FormControl(false));

  this.rolesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    roles: new FormArray(formControls)
  });
}

checkIfTrue(role: Role) {
  // I assume that it should return true if it finds the role in the user.roles array but it doesn't. It doesn't check the box and I get an eror.
  return this.user.roles.find(role);
}
```

I'm getting something like this: `[object Object] is not a function at Array.find`

I have tried the following functions [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the value when building the form instead of using the `[checked]` property, because of the reactive form you use.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsvug5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
ngOnChanges() {
  const formControls = this.roles.map(role => new FormControl(this.checkIfTrue(role)));

  this.rolesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    roles: new FormArray(formControls)
  });
}

checkIfTrue(role) {
  return this.user.roles.find(r => r.uid === role.uid);
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="rolesForm">
  <label 
    formArrayName="roles" 
    *ngFor="let role of rolesForm.controls['roles'].controls; let i = index"
  >
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      [formControlName]="i" 
    /> {{roles[i].name}}
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Your checkIfTrue function did not work, however @upinder kumar 's function did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() return -1 if it does not find elements.
So you can implement something like this:

```
return this.user.roles.indexOf(role) != -1
```

In this way you'll have `true` if indexOf found an element `false` otherwise.

in your checkIfTrue(role: Role) method

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine only change its like that :

```
 checkIfTrue(role: Role) {

   this.user.roles.find(e=>{
    if(e.name === role) {
       return true;
     }
     });
   }
```

Comment: Welcome, Alan s I am happy to help you.